# Xcode stopped detecting SVN repository changes after installing other version controlling apps

Tags: xcode

Last week I installed Source Tree and Github for Dekstop version controlling apps on my Mac, prior to that I am also accessing our companies SVN repository server to contribute on our projects. While I have not installed other apps my SVN repo changes was detectable by Xcode meaning I can push/pull and commit directly from the Xcode.

But after installing those apps Xcode stopped detecting the changes and I feel lost with this.

System Configurations: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)
Xcode Version: 10.0

Any Apple Xcode's expert can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the release notes for Xcode 10 you will see that it has dropped support for SVN repositories.  If you need SVN support then you will need to use a third-party SVN client.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I don't why they removed supporting subversion? Do you suggest any free third-party client for subversion on Mac? For future reader reference: here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes).

Comment: I use an older version of Cornerstone that provides all the functionality that I require.  However, the company that made it, recently sold it to another company and now there is a new version out.  Unfortunately, the new version (and the new company) has received hideous reviews, so I would steer clear of it.  You might want to check out software review sites like [MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com/) to see what is available.  I believe, at one time, I considered Xversion, which looks like it gets fairly good ratings on MacUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode dropped SVN support, you need to use third-party SVN clients

[SnailSVN](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/snailsvn-lite-svn-for-finder/id1063090543?mt=12) is good - its like TortoiseSVN on Windows

[svnX](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/svnx/html/Downloads.html) another free SVN client but bad GUI.